# Terraform for aws_alb_listener how to add multiple target_group_arn in default action for type="forward"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

**My Approach:** I have to create an "aws_lb_listener" resource , in the default action I have type = " forward" but I don't have one target_group_arn . I have more than one target_group_arn values.

Below snippet shows frontend-listener but the target_group_arn should include more than one arn values.

```
resource "aws_alb_listener" "frontend-listener" {
    load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.ss_alb.arn
    port = "443" #"80" 
    protocol = "HTTPS"
    depends_on        = [aws_alb_target_group.aws_alb_target_group]
    
    default_action {
    #target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.aws_alb_target_group.arn
    type = "forward"
    
    }
}
```

The aws_alb_target_group resource shows multiple target-group being created .

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "aws_alb_target_group" {
    for_each = local.ebapp_name

    name = "${each.value.name}-tg"
    port = 80
    protocol = "HTTP"
    vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}
```

I have looked at the terraform documentation but couldn't get a solution. (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_listener)

```
resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "aws_alb_listener_rule"{
    for_each = local.ebapp_name

    listener_arn = aws_alb_listener.frontend-listener.arn
    action {    
          type = "forward"    
          target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.aws_alb_target_group[each.value.name].arn
    }   
    condition {    
         
         path_pattern {
            values = ["/${each.value.name}/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

I have also mentioned the Listener rules .

The error is shown with terraform apply command and it is as below:

for actions of type 'forward', you must specify a 'forward' block or 'target_group_arn'

What changes to make to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve that using [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks). For example:

```
resource "aws_alb_listener" "frontend-listener" {
    load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.ss_alb.arn
    port = "443" #"80" 
    protocol = "HTTPS"
    depends_on        = [aws_alb_target_group.aws_alb_target_group]
    
    default_action {        
        type = "forward"
        forward {
            dynamic "target_group" {
                for_each = aws_alb_target_group.aws_alb_target_group
                content {
                    arn = target_group.value["arn"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is example only, and some adjustment may still be required to make it work as expected.

Comment: I tried with 


forward {
            dynamic "target_group" {
                for_each = local.ebapp_name
                content {
                    arn = aws_alb_target_group.aws_alb_target_group[each.value.name].arn             
                }
            }
        }

It doesn't seem to work , can you suggest any way it might work ?? Been stuck on it for long time now.

Comment: Error: each.value cannot be used in this context

  on modules\alb\main.tf line 37, in resource "aws_alb_listener" "frontend-listener":
  37:                     arn = aws_alb_target_group.aws_alb_target_group[each.value.name].arn

A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it
unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in
its "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your
configuration to work around this error.

Comment: @aditmodi In my answer I used `each.value`. It was also wrong?

Comment: @aditmodi Maybe it should be `target_group.value["arn"]`. I modified the answer.

Comment: your answer didn't work as for_each should have local.ebapp_name and not resource.aws_alb_target_group.aws_alb_target_group .

Comment: I see. Can you try then with with  `target_group.value["name"]`?

Comment: I am sure `target_group.value["name"]` doesnot work.

Comment: I have got the Answer on how to get this done in a static way.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. It adds now all three target groups to the defualt action of the listener.

```
locals {
  target_groups = ["1", "2", "3"]
}


resource "aws_lb_listener" "https_to_target_group" {
  count = length(local.target_groups)

  certificate_arn   = aws_acm_certificate.cd.arn
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.cd.arn

  port              = var.alb.port
  protocol          = var.alb.protocol
  ssl_policy        = var.alb.ssl_policy

  default_action {

    type             = "forward"
    forward {
      dynamic "target_group" {
        for_each = local.target_groups
        content {
          arn = aws_lb_target_group.cd[target_group.key].arn
        }
      }
    }
  }
```